# e.target not found in jest unit testing for react component eventhandler, despite passing in second parameter to enzyme's .simulate()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

so I have a select dropdown where users can select from a list of provinces.

```
                    <select
                        className="province-select"
                        onChange={this.regionSelected}
                    >
                        <option>
                            Ontario
                        </option>
                        <option>
                            Quebec
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

In my unit test, I want to trigger the on change event and check that this.regionSelected is called as expected

```
const wrapperSuccess = shallow(<RegionSelector {...validData} />);

        wrapperSuccess.find(".province-select").simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Ontario' } });
```

My RegionSelector component runs and works fun in an actual environment.  However, when I run the unit test above, I get the following error:

Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

```
setCurrentRegion(e.target.value)
```

the setCurrentRegion is the first line of code which calls upon e.target.value inside the change handler function this.regionSelected.  I checked enzyme's documentation and several other stack overflow answers, and they all say to pass in a second event object.  But I am!  And still e.target is not found.  What am I missing?  Thanks

Comment: Is `wrapperSuccess.find("province-select")` returning anything? Selector looks like it should be `.province-select` instead.

Comment: yes it is. Sorry that's my typo, the classname was much longer so I shortened it and forgot to copy the . in front.  Corrected.  But it is returning correctly

Answer (score 0):

Okie!  Figured it out.  It seems the reason is because the eventHandler is a method on the component itself.  If it was a eventHandler passed in through props, it would've been okay.  But for some reason using jest's shallow(), even by passing in a second parameter to the simulate() function, the eventHandler won't receive it.  I've worked around it by spying on the prototype of the component itself, and that seemed to work